# How to make a "squared gradient" in Adobe Animate (or Photoshop, XD, or Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, gradient, adobe-xd, adobe-animate

I would prefer to do this in Animate, although if it's possible to do it in Photoshop, XD, or Illustrator instead, I would be interested in learning that technique as well.

In Adobe Animate, I can apply a radial gradient fill to a shape and then tweak the gradient with the Gradient Transform tool. However, I want to make a "squared gradient" which is a concept I am making up in my head since I've never seen it before in any graphics program.

What I want is something like a radial gradient, but rather than the gradient effect having a round shape, I want it to have a square or rectangular shape. In the image below, the best that I can achieve with a radial gradient is an oval shape.

[image]

What I want instead is a rectangular gradient fill that is clear in the center and fades to yellow at the edges, like in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* simply apply a gradient to a thick stroke in **Illustrator**.....

[image]

Or as a Layer Style stroke set to `Shape Burst` in **Photoshop**....

[image]

I wouldn't know about XD or Animate.

Comment: This is terrific, thank you, Scott! It's a bit of a workaround to import from PS/Illustrator into Animate, but I'll mark this as the answer since it doesn't seem to be possible to do this directly in Animate. But if someone knows how to achieve this gradient effect natively in Animate I would be happy to know!